# scoping in shiny flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) that uses shiny. Here's a [MRE repo](https://github.com/ericpgreen/Nivi-classify-example) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/ericpgreen/a00406c82cf1e37d4e8273a41988bd3c) of the `.Rmd`. When I put the app live on shinyapps.io, I realized that one user's actions could affect other users. I understand that this is a scoping issue, but I'm confused about how scoping works in Flexdashboard.

[This page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) explains scoping for 'regular' shiny apps:

> You might want some objects to be visible across all sessions. For example, if you have large data structures, or if you have utility functions that are not reactive (ones that don’t involve the input or output objects), then you can create these objects once and share them across all user sessions (within the same R process), by placing them in app.R , but outside of the server function definition.

In Flexdashboard, there is no `app.R` file or `server` function. How does scoping work in these types of shiny apps?

I have several `eventReactive()` functions like this that get updated for User 2 when User 1 hits submit and triggers `observeEvent(input$submit, {})` at the end of the file.

```
eventReactive(rv$run2, {

    if (remote==1) {
      master$df <- drop_read_csv("/dash/master.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    } else {
      master$df <- read.csv("dash/master.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }

  }, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
```

I originally [posted this to RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-scoping-in-flexdashboard/15584) about 9 hours ago, but it did not generate many views (<20) or any discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving `rv <- reactiveValues()` out of the `global` chunk did the trick.